# Video server and html5, mobile device

Tags: html, streaming, red5

I have one server with red5 serving streaming, and working fine. Now want work with html5 for mobile devices, like cellphones and tablets (android).
How best way for this, using streaming and html5?  How best format? ogg, webm, mp4? Offer some files with many formats or convert in real time from server?